# Does Coverity Scan support multiple Git branches?

Tags: git, coverity

I have an Open Source project, which is being developed in three Git branches of the same Git repo (say `v9_11`, `v9_14`, and `master`. I want all these branches to be periodically scanned in Coverity Scan.

If I register this project with the Git repo and then subsequently upload results from different Git branches to the same Coverity Scan project, I get sub-optimal results like "New defects found: 2" and "Defects eliminated: 1" only because the last branch analyzed is different.

Is it possible to have per-branch results in Coverity Scan from one registered project/Git repo?

If not, I guess I have to create three Git repos and each register as a Coverity Scan project.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can.

From their [documentation](https://scan.coverity.com/travis_ci):

> To increase availability of the free service to more projects, the
>   addon is designed by default to run analysis on a per-branch basis

Recommendation:

Create a branch named `coverity_scan`, which you can merge into whenever you would like to trigger analysis.

***EDITED***

But too many will get you in "trouble".

The number of weekly builds per project are as follows:

```
Up to 28 builds per week, with a maximum of 4 builds per day, for projects with fewer than 100K lines of code
Up to 21 builds per week, with a maximum of 3 builds per day, for projects with 100K to 500K lines of code
Up to 14 builds per week, with a maximum of 2 build per day, for projects with 500K to 1 million lines of code
Up to 7 builds per week, with a maximum of 1 build per day, for projects with more than 1 million lines of code
```

> Once a project reaches the maximum builds per week, additional build
>   requests will be rejected. You will be able to re-submit the build
>   request the following week.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the documentation, @amer. However, as I understand it, this wont work in my use case in which I have three branches where the software is being developed and from which is later released. Such a `coverity_scan` branch would not reflect any of current branches content, certainly not in terms of defect removal progress. It could work for analyzing Merge Requests, but we have too many MRs to fit into the service criteria.

Comment: I tried to help. As doc and forum said. Overanalysing is often overkill. So maybe analysis on master is enough. Idk.